# Why is the import statement importing a function outside of the class that is being imported?

Tags: python, django

I was under the understanding that using the syntax:

```
from foo import y
```

will import the class y from foo.py.

If this is true how come when I use the following:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from .utils import codeGenerator, createShortcode

class KirrUrlManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs_main = super(KirrUrlManager, self).all(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = qs_main.filter(active=True)
        return qs

    def refreshShortCodes(self):
        qs = KirrUrl.objects.filter(id__gte=1)  #id_gte is primary key
        newCodes = 0
        for q in qs:
            q.shortcode = createShortcode(q)
            q.save()
            newCodes +=1
        return "new codes made: {i} ".format(i=newCodes)

class KirrUrl(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=220, unique=True)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True,)

    objects = KirrUrlManager()


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.shortcode is None or self.shortcode =="":
            self.shortcode = createShortcode(self)
        super(KirrUrl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.url)
```

foo.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from shortener.models import KirrUrl

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "refreshes all shortcodes"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        return KirrUrl.objects.refreshShortCodes()
```

I am unsure why I am able to call the method "refreshShortCodes()" in foo.py. I am only using the import statement "from shortener.models import KirrUrl". Shouldnt this import statement only let me import the KirrUrl class? refreshShortCodes() is not part of the KirrUrl class, however it is the models.py file that is being imported.

Comment: What is the error you are currently getting indicating how it is not working. Also, I don't know much about Django, so I'm not sure what `KirrUrl.objects` does, but considering `KirrUrl` is a class, and you are trying to access an instance method, don't you have to get an instance first, by calling `KirrUrl()`?

Comment: I am not getting an error. I was under the understanding that import statements would import everything from a file. I was curious to know why the method refreshshortcodes() is being imported when im only importing the class KirrUrl()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldnt this import statement only let me import the KirrUrl class?

Yes, and that's exactly what the `import` statement is doing. `objects.refreshShortCodes()` *is* part of the `KirrUrl` class. So you have access to the class name, as well as its attributes.

When Python imports a class, it imports the *entire* class object. That means all of variables and methods defined in the classes namespace can be reached. So Since you created an instance of `KirrUrlManager()` inside of the `KirrUrl` class, you can access the `refreshShortCodes()` method by first getting the `KirrUrlManager()` instance:

```
KirrUrl.objects
```

And then getting the `refreshShortCodes()` method from the `KirrUrlManager()` instance:

```
KirrUrl.objects.refreshShortCodes()
```

Comment: Iisnt it part of the KirrUrlManager class, not the KirrUrl class?

Comment: @salty_coffee Yes. But you create an instance of the `KirrUrlManager()` class_ in_ the `KirrUrl` namespace. So you can access  `refreshShortCodes()` from the instance of `KirrUrlManager()` defined in the `KirrUrl()` class.

Comment: I get it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help @salty_coffee.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to import the class to have access to its attributes; you can't import an object encapsulated in a class.

Therefore, after importing the class `KirrUrl`, the model manager `objects` is accessible via the class, and the method `refreshShortCodes` is equally accessible via the model manager instance which is composed in the class `KirrUrl`.

This is one of the ways objects that are not **reachable** by the import mechanism are accessed; dot referencing.